# Visual Studio Setup Project Custom Dialog

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-installer, installation, projects

I have created a custom dialog for Visual Studio Setup Project using the steps described
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/vsSetupCustomDialogs.aspx?fid=419622&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2640482&fr=26)

Now I have a combobox in one of my dialogs. I want to populate the combobox with a list of all SQL Server instances running on the local network. It's trivial to get the server list ... but I'm completely lost on how to make them display in the combobox. I would appreciate your help and some code might also be nice as I'm beginner :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've always found the custom dialogs in visual studio setup projects to be woefully limited and barely functional.

By contrast, I normally create custom actions that display winforms gui's for any remotely difficult tasks during setup.  Works really well and you can do just about anything you want by creating a custom action and passing a few parameters across.

In the dayjob we built a collection of common custom actions for tasks like application config and database creation / script execution to get around custom dialog limitations.

Comment: I finally switched to WiX installer which is much more configurable, also with respect to the UI.

Comment: hi David, How do you manage to set focus to winform displaying as custom action. I trying your method, but always focus goes to main setup window not to the winform.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya from memory, I never had any problems with focus, but my memory of 2008 is somewhat hazey alas!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll have to go beyond the out-of-the-box setup and deployment package and try a third party app.

You may want to look at:

- [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)
- [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Both are free; they might give you the customization that you need.