# Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I need to build a setup project for an windows application I developed in C#. Along the way, I need the user to be able to set the database server/instance name along with authentication type, and a username /password if they are using SQL authentication. This connection string is stored in my app.config file.

Once setup is complete, a website needs to open that will install a couple of controls that are needed for this application.

I have been looking at how to develop setup projects but I can't seem to figure out how to do what I need to do.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a custom dialog in the setup project as shown [Create custom dialogs for use in your Visual Studio Setup projects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/vsSetupCustomDialogs.aspx)

One interesting way to do it is to use custom action with "normal" winform like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439/visual-studio-setup-project-custom-dialog)

Take a look at Wix, i tested it for a small application/addin, works fine.
For your problem more work to to, but i think if you create your Wix modular you can put the parts together for a new setup application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build an InstallHelper exe that will run during the standard VS Setup Project as described at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/ec13b205-9a90-496f-9d7b-ccebdf1d3ca1/build-a-custom-action-ins.aspx.